# Is it possible to dismiss all notifications?

Tags: civilization-6

Is it possible to somehow dismiss all notifications, instead of right-clicking one at a time?

What I am thinking about is this little problem:

[image: Notifications]

Here, I have 25 notifications after a couple of peace agreements. It is quite tedious to do around 30 right clicks.

Comment: I can try and check to confirm but pretty sure it's either click through them, or wait until next turn when they'll clear.

Comment: I don't know about CIV6 but there probably is a mod for that. Look in the steam workshop

Comment: @n_palum Ignoring them is definitely an option. Silly that I didn't think about it.

Comment: @BlueWizard Searched throgh the workshop but did unfortunately not find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can right click the little number and it will dismiss all of them.

Comment: I don't know if this always worked, but it certainly did now.

Comment: I think this was added at some point, potentially in the newest dlc

Answer (score 1):

As I had mentioned in a comment, there really isn't a way to mass remove notifications unfortunately. You can go through and click them one at a time till they are gone, but as an alternative, you can **wait until your next turn**. On the new turn old notifications (for the most part) will be gone.

I believe certain notifications stay until you remove them, like who built wonders or players being defeated but I can't say which ones for sure.

As was also pointed out, there aren't really mods for the game that help you clear them faster either.

Comment: As an attempt to answer which notifications stick: unit promotions, war/peace declarations, player defeat, player close to victory, starving/low housing/low amenity cities, cities converted to free cities, free cities captured by a player. Those are all the ones I can think of.